Looking for the origin of this (paraphrased) quote
I remember reading a few years ago something like

"No one has ever proven that life is something to be taken seriously".

I think it might have been in a book by Douglas Adams, but if that is the case, he might have been quoting someone else. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me who said that and where.

There is a quote attributed to Brendan Gill as follows:

Not a shred of evidence exists in favor of the idea that life is serious.

Different wording to yours but in essence it's the same message.

Thanks @Killing Time, that is very probably it, although the name Brendan Gill doesn't ring a bell at all, reinforcing my idea that it was being quoted by someone else, probably.
